# fullcalendar get resources from Mysql DB by using php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, fullcalendar

I am using fullcalendar-scheduler-1.9.4. I am trying to get resources from my database. I get json array of my resources by php. However, the problem is businessHours and event color of my resources does not appear. the more weird thing is from 5 resources, only one resource get the right eventcolor. I checked the output of my php file, but it gave correct json array to resources. I don't know what is wrong here...

Here is my php code for get resource array

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "dbname", "pass", "dbname");
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT Teacher, color FROM TEACHERLIST WHERE Branch = '잠실';");
$response = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    array_push($response, array("title"=>$row[0], "id" => $row[0], "eventColor" => $row[1], "businessHours" => "{start: '08:00',end: '22:30', dow: [1,2,3,4,5,6]}"));
}

echo json_encode($response,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Here is my javascript where I get the resources.

```
resources: 'teacher_J.php',
resourceAreaWidth: "10%",
eventSources:[ {url:'array_S.php'},{url:'dayS.php'}],
```

And my result looks like this

[wrong result when I use php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NqDG.png)

the correct result is this,

[right result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dj4bp.png)

I got this result when I didn't use php to load resources. 
the javascript code that makes right result is this

```
 resources:[{ id: 'A', title: 'A', businessHours : {start: '08:00',end: '22:30', dow: [1,2,3,4,5,6]} },
            { id: 'B', title: 'B', eventColor: 'green' , businessHours : {start: '08:00',end: '22:30', dow: [1,2,3,4,5,6]}},
            { id: 'C', title: 'C', eventColor: 'orange', businessHours : {start: '08:00',end: '22:30', dow: [1,2,3,4,5,6]} },
            { id: 'D', title: 'D', eventColor: 'Brown' , businessHours : {start: '08:00',end: '22:30', dow: [1,2,3,4,5,6]} },
            { id: 'E', title: 'E', eventColor: 'blue' , businessHours : {start: '08:00',end: '22:30', dow: [1,2,3,4,5,6]}}],
```

The only thing that is different between two of them is the way I load the resources.

+) JSON output from PHP

```
[
  {"title":"a","id":"a","eventColor":"MediumAquaMarine ","businessHours":"{start: '08:00',end: '22:30', dow: [1,2,3,4,5,6]}"},
  {"title":"b","id":"b","eventColor":"green","businessHours":"{start: '08:00',end: '22:30', dow: [1,2,3,4,5,6]}"},
  {"title":"c","id":"c","eventColor":"orange","businessHours":"{start: '08:00',end: '22:30', dow: [1,2,3,4,5,6]}"},
  {"title":"d","id":"d","eventColor":"red","businessHours":"{start: '08:00',end: '22:30', dow: [1,2,3,4,5,6]}"},
  {"title":"e","id":"e","eventColor":"blue","businessHours":"{start: '08:00',end: '22:30', dow: [1,2,3,4,5,6]}"}
]
```

Comment: You didn't make clear, but I assume the problem is related to the colours of the events? Or is there anything else as well? It would be useful to know. Anyway please show us the final JSON produced by `echo json_encode($response,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);`. It's impossible for us to know whether it's your code, or the data in your database which is at fault. Seeing the JSON might help us to understand.

Comment: @ADyson I edited. I think eventcolor and businessHours have some problem. not only color but also businessHours are not working properly when I give the resources by json.

Comment: well, the data you gave manually, and the JSON coming from your PHP have totally different values in them. You're not using the same colours. Also `a` != `A` - check whether your event data associated with the resources has the resource IDs in upper-case or lower-case. Make sure that, whichever case you use, they match on both the event and resource data.

Comment: As for businesHours, you're sending that property as a single string (which looks like JSON, but is not treated as JSON by JavaScript) instead of an actual object. There should not be double-quotes before and after the `{` and `}` of your business hours. i.e. `"businessHours":"{start: '08:00',end: '22:30', dow: [1,2,3,4,5,6]}"` would have to be `"businessHours":{start: '08:00',end: '22:30', dow: [1,2,3,4,5,6]}` as per your example when you declare the resources manually.

Comment: @ADyson I fixed some resource ID when I uploading it, because there are some name of my friends, so in actual code, color and resource Id are matched. So, as for businessHours, you mean that I need to separate start, end, and dow? Actually, when I get json of event, I works. I think it will solve the problem of businessHours. However, what makes me confusing is why only green resource appear correctly but nothing else? there is nothing special about green resource... isn't it?

Comment: Businesshours sholuld be an object in your PHP, not a string. `"businessHours" => array("start" =>  "08:00", "end" => "22:30", "dow" => [1,2,3,4,5,6])`.
But no, there's nothing special about the green resource. Must be something else I can't see from the code

Comment: @ADyson OMG!!! I find what is wrong. In the mysql DB, I use excel to import data. However, I put the one space after resource Id, for example "A ", but only green resource have no space after Id like "C". That makes the green resource works!!! I couldn't believe this makes a huge problem and it took most of my night!!!!........

Comment: ah...glad you found it. In future, always trim your data to remove whitespace when importing! That kind of thing has happened to me, it's really frustrating because you (literally!) can't see what's wrong.